# Redirect all traffic to construction page except my IP in .htaccess

Tags: apache, htaccess

The title pretty much says it all.

I want to direct all traffic to an under construction page except for traffic originating from my IP address so I can move a large development site into production and tweak a few things along the way.

Any way to do this in .htaccess?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} != 192.168.1.0 #your ip goes here
RewriteRule !^maintanence$ maintanence [L]
```

Comment: If I do this I get a 500 internal server error: RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} != 192.168.1.0 
RewriteRule construction.php [L]

Comment: Yeah, and even when I don't change the IP I don't get redirected to the under construction page, I get a 500 Internal Server error instead.

Comment: Yes, I changed the IP in the example to my IP and still get a 500 Internal Server Error.

Comment: Hmm... that's interesting. Try this: `RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} != 192.168.1.0 #your ip goes here
RewriteRule ^/$ construction.php [L]`

Comment: Yeah, still 500'd  =(

Comment: Check the `error.log` of your Apache httpd. I guess that `mod_rewrite` simply hasn't been loaded or that `AllowOverride` forbids the use of `.htaccess` files.

Comment: I don't think that's the case, I have many RewriteCond and RewriteRule statements in my .htaccess files that are being processed correctly.  I've even tried taking all existing statements out and using the above code and I still get a 500 error.

Comment: Have you tried enclosing the ip in quotes and escaping the periods? `"192\.168\.1\.0"` Or make the ip in question more generalized: `"^192\.168\.1\."`

Comment: [http://davidwalsh.name/htaccess-maintenance-page-redirect](http://davidwalsh.name/htaccess-maintenance-page-redirect) || [http://www.techiecorner.com/97/redirect-to-maintenance-page-during-upgrade-using-htaccess/](http://www.techiecorner.com/97/redirect-to-maintenance-page-during-upgrade-using-htaccess/)

Answer (score 1):

in .htaccess, i am nt sure bt with php u can do this...
Create index.php using following code

```
<?php
header ("Location:./under-construction/");
?>
```

keep this index.php file in public_html folder and your users will directly redirected to under construction page and u can check ur work directly entering ur page for exampale: xyz.com/demo/ or if your real page file(index.php) and should be located in same folder public_html than rename ur real page name frm index.php to demo.html for a while...